# Problem with Join fetch in Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my JPA application, I encountered an error when attempting to use a **`join fetch`** clause within a select query. The error message I received was as follows:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [SqmListJoin(com.knitkota.jpademo.entity.UserEntity(u).addressEntities(a))]`

Interestingly, I noticed that the **`join fetch`** operation worked successfully when used without the select statement.

In the provided repository, particularly in the **`ServiceClass.java`** file, you can observe two methods implemented in the **`UserRepository.java`** class. The method **`userRepository.findAllJoinFetch();`** executes without any issues. However, the method **`userRepository.findAllJoinFetchDto();`** triggers the error mentioned above.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance in comprehending the underlying problem related to the **`join fetch`** operation.

Thank you for your assistance in clarifying this matter.

Git repository: https://github.com/pervez8ktt/SpringBootJpaDemo

Comment: You cannot do joins with projections.

Comment: Joins with projections is possible. If I will use left join or other joins. Only join fetch creates problem

Comment: hello! join fetch fetches the right association of the join. in your case the semantic exception is raised because the return type does not need to fetch the association because your query does not return the association. if the return type contains the association, join fetch will raise no semantic exception. if the return type does not contain the association that was join fetched, than a semantic exception is thrown.